# Check fallback key testing in enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I'm doing unit-testing for component props in reactjs with jest and enzyme library.

Here all I need to test, *undefined key of JSON data* & fallback for that keys written or not...

Here are pseudo code:

```
    export class ActivityItem extends React.Component {
      render() {
        const { activity } = this.props;
        return (
          <div className='item'>
            <p>{activity.item}</p>
          </div>)
        }
     }
```

JSON Date:

```
[{"id": 1,
  "item": "Rose"},
{ "id": 2,
  "item": "Susain"}]
```

Testing cases

```
  describe('check fallback for text key', () => {
    it('has value in text key', () => {
      wrapper = wrapper.find('ActivityItem')
      expect(wrapper.find('p').length).toBeGreaterThan(1);
    })
  })
```

Here I could not find `<p>` tag to check its value for test...

Comment: What is the initial value for `wrapper`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to shallow render the component first and look up the element with selectors.

Here's a snippet that might help.

```
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import ActivityItem from 'wherever-it-is';

describe('check fallback for text key', () => {
  it('has value in text key', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<ActivityItem activity={'meow'}/>);
    expect(wrapper.find('.item > p').length).toEqual(1);
  })
})
```